# Where does phTagr set the requests 'search' parameter?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am fairly new to cakePHP, i am trying to work with [**phtagr**](http://www.phtagr.org/) which uses cakePHP. I am trying to fix a pagination problem it has.
when i see the output of `$this->request->params['search']` it has the pagecount value.

```
function beforeRender($viewFile) {
       $this->search->iniitialize();

       if(isset($this->request->params['search'])){

         $this->data = am($this->defaults, $this->request->params['search']);
         $this->data['page'] = 1;
       }
    } else {
        $this->data = $this->defaults;
     }
  }
```

printing `$this->request->params['search']` gives

```
    Array ( [pageCount] => 27683 [current] => 0 [nextPage] => 1 [prevPage] => [baseUri] => /explorer/query [afterUri] => [defaults] => Array ( [page] => 1 [pos] => [show] => 24 [sort] => -date [view] => small ) [data] => Array ( ) [page] => )
```

How can i find out where the `pageCount` value is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search the source files for the string `'search'`. For example using `grep`:

```
grep -r "'search'" /path/to/phTagr/
```

Results:

```
...
Controller/Component/SearchComponent.php: $this->controller->request->params['search'] = $params;
...
```

ie it's being set in the search component.

Comment: thanx, I found it :)